# How to filter data with Style format in Euros + pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas

I have a database and i have some problems when i used the Style format(Euros)

```
df.head(3).style.format({'Budget': "€{:,.0f}"})
    Year    Project Entity  Participation   Country Budget
0   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   'FUNDACION IMDEA NETWORK*'  Participant Spain   €384,000
1   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   'ROHDE & SCHWARZ GMBH*' Participant Germany €12,000
2   2015    671650 - MMMAGIC - 5G   'SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS (UK) LIMITED'  Coordinator UnitedKingdom   €997,500
```

The problem is when i apply this filter:

```
display(df.groupby('Entity')['Budget'].agg(['sum'])
.sort_values('sum', ascending=False).head(3).style.format('€ {0:,.0f}'))

                                                sum
```

Entity
FRAUNHOFER GESELLSCHAFT EV                  € 18,550,842
TELEFONICA INVESTIGACION Y DESARROLLO SA*   € 13,592,263
ORANGE SA*                                  €  9,517,402

I will like to have a result like this:

```
Country        Entity                                                                             
Germany  FRAUNHOFER GESELLSCHAFT EV                     € 18550842.50
Spain    TELEFONICA INVESTIGACION Y DESARROLLO SA*      € 13592263.26
France   ORANGE SA*                                     € 9517402.06
```

but when i applied the command:

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Entity'])['Budget'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

i obtained the same but without euros symbol, please any suggestion to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a Series object that has no 'style' method, so you must call 'to_frame()':

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Entity'])['Budget'].sum()  \
             .sort_values(ascending=False)  \
             .to_frame()  \
             .style.format('€ {0:,.0f}')
```

Comment: Thanks for answer the question, Maybe you could help me with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59069000/pandas-python-format-for-values